# convert iostat output to .JSON

Tags: json, linux, iostat

do you have any idea on how I can turn my iostat output into JSON and put it into a .JSON file?

I'm working under an Amazon Linux 2 instance.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

iostat -o JSON

Type iostat —help show more manual.